# Вывод горизонтальной линии в ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер, vga

Как оптимально быстро вывести линию используя ассемблер? Видео адаптер VGA 640x480, 16 цветов. Я устанавливаю маску видео адаптера и маску цвета.

```
; Маска вывода точек
MOV  DX,3CEH        
MOV  AL,8           
OUT  DX,AL          
INC  DX             
MOV  AL,0FFH        
OUT  DX,AL           
; маска цвета
MOV  DX,3C4H        
MOV  AL,2           
OUT  DX,AL          
INC  DX             
MOV  AL,var_color   
OUT  DX,AL

MOV CX, counter

label:
paiting  ; макрос вывода точки
loop label
```

Вывожу по-байтно, в цикле, но мне сказали, что есть более быстрый способ. Кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такое понятие как выполнение цепочных команд. Используя данный подход, код будет таким.

```
; Начало как и раньше
; Маска вывода точек
MOV  DX,3CEH        
MOV  AL,8           
OUT  DX,AL          
INC  DX             
MOV  AL,0FFH        
OUT  DX,AL           
; маска цвета
MOV  DX,3C4H        
MOV  AL,2           
OUT  DX,AL          
INC  DX             
MOV  AL,var_color   
OUT  DX,AL

; Теперь рисуем 
MOV CX, counter          ; Как и раньше
MOV DI, point_location   ; Устанавливаем смещение на начало 
REP STOSB                ; Выполняем цепочную команду
```

В DI находится стартовая точка, в СX количество итераций. Таким образом можно выводить только целые байты. Если линия начинается не с начала байта, то сперва выводится дробная часть, а со следующего байта можно использовать цепочные команды.